# Function as properties and undefined method

Tags: php

I am making a game, and came to the part to implement character abilities on the server-side.

So I have an array to hold all character abilities:

```
$abils = array();
```

And a class for them:

```
class Abil{
    private $timing;
    private $func;

    public function __construct($time, $func){
        global $abils;
        $this->timing = $time;
        $this->func = $func;
        array_push($abils,$this);
    }

    public function trigger($time,$params){
        if(preg_match('/^'.$this->timing.'$/',$time)) $this->func($params);
    }
}
```

`$time` is the "timing" of the ability, as RegEx. For example, `\d\d-0` would be the start of anyone's turn.
`$func` is a function to run when the ability is used.

When a certain "timing" is reached (for example, the start of someone's turn), a global `triggerAll()` function would be used to trigger all abilities of that timing:

```
function triggerAll($time,$params = NULL){
    global $abils;
    foreach($abils as $abil) $abil->trigger($time,$params);
}
```

But then, when `triggerAll` is called, a fatal error is generated:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Abil::func()`

I suspect this is due to `$func` not being a METHOD but a PROPERTY which holds a function. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround: [`call_user_func`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

```
call_user_func($this->func,$params);
```

instead of

```
$this->func($params);
```

Comment: @nick: Surely not. That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Eric - Surely? Well, I would check again - [Definitively, it works](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iIZyei).

Comment: @nickb: we're talking about different things. I was under the impression `func` contained a function, not the name of a member.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this will work:

```
$f = $this->func;
$f($params);
```

And perhaps (although probably only in 5.5)

```
($this->func)($params);
```